# File not accessible error (setuptools) in logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, warnings, setuptools

When I run my app, my app engine logs give me this error:

```
WARNING  2012-03-01 23:27:31,089 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open 
zipfile/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: 
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg'
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you have marked as accepted isn't helpful. An [annoying bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7301) in the App Engine SDK actually throws these errors when running the development server with Python 2.7. Here's how I fixed it:

- Edit the file `<local path to app engine>/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py`

  - On most systems the local path to App Engine is `/usr/local/google_appengine`
- Search for `py27_optional=False` (around line 477) and replace it with `py27_optional=True`

Every time you update your local App Engine SDK, you will need to redo this patch.

Credit [Carl D'Halluin](http://www.rogerthat.net/2012/12/07/running-google-app-engine-development-server-with-python2-7/)

Answer (score 1):

Errno 13 is EACCES. It means "permission denied". So the access permissions do not allow you to access that file. Check the permissions with `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`

A list of error names and explanations is usually found in the manual page for `errno`, or the C include file `errno.h`.

Comment: having the same issue, the file has -rw-r--r-- permissions, which is consistent with other packages, and should allow read access. 
how do i solve it?

Comment: Try open()-ing the file in question in an interactive Python interpreter. Does that work? If not, do you get the same exception?

Comment: I have the same problem - the permissions are -rw-r--r-- as well. When I open it in a python interpreter it opens() fine and read() works on it as well, so I'm at a bit of a loss...

Answer (score 1):

This may happen after building a new library. For example, it happened to me after building lxml. Remake your symlinks from the appengine and it should fix your issue.

Comment: This is probably a dumb question - but is it possible to remake symlinks on linux via the command line? the only reference I've seen to it is for the GUIs on OSX and Windows...